# Why isn't my id preserved of the @ModelAttribute?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Why isn't my id preserved of the @ModelAttribute? Why do I have to send it as a hidden parameter in my form? Shouldn't spring handle this when using command?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{supplierId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String get(@PathVariable Long supplierId,  Model model, Principal principal){

    Form form = .... //Got a an existing form from DB
    model.addAttribute("form", form);

    return "/form";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/{supplierId}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String post(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable Long supplierId, @Valid @ModelAttribute("form") Form form, BindingResult result, Model model, Principal principal){

    System.out.println(form.getID()); //Here the id is 0

    safeFoodFormService.store(form, supplierId);
    return "redirect:/supplier";
}
```

My Freemarker form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="<@spring.url "/forms/${supplier.ID?c}"/>" method="post" command="form">
```

It will work if I do add this lines inside my form

```
<@spring.bind "form.ID" /> 

<input type="hidden"  name="${spring.status.expression}" value="${spring.status.value default("")}" />
```

I would be very nice if this could be handled by Spring. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Spring data binding takes the request name/value pair and binds the corresponding properties with same name to corresponding value. So if there is no id request parameter present in request, spring mvc has no way to map its value in the model bean which would be injected in to the controller method. So by any mechanism the form must have a input (hidden or otherwise) to let the spring bind its value to the bean property.